# Raspberry Pi Chromium Error 137

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I have seen on google this error has been posted for windows machines, and google chrome. However I am using a raspberry pi and I am having this issue, please see below.

So I have a Raspberry Pi, the newest model. I am running chromium to display a dashboard. Every hour or so the thing crashes with a white screen, and the error is

The webpage at (url here) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED)L Unknown error

As soon as I hit refresh on the web browser everything works for about another hour or so. Any ideas what I can try to fix this on the raspberry pi. Most sites say how to fix this on windows.

Comment: One thing to note is I have tried every available browser for the raspberry pi, and I have the same exact error on every browser... midori, epiphany.. etc

Comment: Are you displaying a single webpage or rotating through multiple webpages?